# Where Are Exit Codes For Cron Jobs Stored In Centos / Red Hat Servers?

Tags: cron, exit-code

I just need to know:

1. Our systems are set up to use /var/log/cron to store cron logs, however, there are no exit codes stored here just start/stop times and the PID of the jobs. How can I force our servers to just log a simple exit code for the cron job?

Note: I'm not trying to force the script that is being called to report its own exit code I just wanted to see if it was possible that Cron itself could log is own exit status. Almost if you were able to do an echo $? right after it ran to see what the code was.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to get the return value by referring to `$?` - a users crontab (which is not allowed to write to `/root/no-no`) it looks like this:

```
 24      15      *       *       *       /bin/echo "foo"; logger \`echo $?\`
 25      15      *       *       *       /bin/echo "bar" > /root/no-no; logger \`echo $?\`
```

then see the output of logger in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are lookin for,

```
/60 * * * *  /path/to/Script >/path/to/log 2>&1; [ $? != 0 ] && mail -s "SUBJECT" -E email@example.com < /path/to/log
```

This will notify you when exit code is not equal to 0 or when cron job will fail.